# SonarQube Read timeout on /batch/project after upgrade from 4.5.1 to 4.5.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Upgraded SonarQube from 4.5.1 to 4.5.2 today.

After this I get the following error when analysing a project with 220.000+ lines/400 rules with Maven

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project X: Unable to request: /batch/project?key=<mykey>&preview=false: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
```

I have tried to access the URL in a browser, and it takes about 3min and 10 seconds to complete.

Analysing smaller projects still works as before

Any tips?

Database is MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution was to turn on full debug logging, identify the SQL culprits and then manually add indices and statistics.
Hopefully this will not break future db-upgrades